# Perl module XML::Compile::WSDL11: Body isn't added to request

Tags: perl, wsdl

I'm trying to build a WSDL client using [XML::Compile::WSDL11](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Compile::WSDL11) and this [WSDL](https://wiki.unify.com/images/d/d7/OpenScape_Voice_V9%2C_WSDL_file.zip). The Operation in question is GetBGList3.

The problem is: The created request doesn't contain the body.

The example code is:

```
use XML::Compile::SOAP11;
use XML::Compile::WSDL11;
use XML::Compile::Transport::SOAPHTTP;

use Log::Report mode => 'VERBOSE';   # or 'VERBOSE' 'DEBUG'

my $wsdl_file="OpenScape-Voice.wsdl";
my $url="http://127.0.0.1:80/test";
my $ope="GetBGList3";

my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new;
$wsdl->addWSDL($wsdl_file);

$wsdl->compileCall($ope,address => $url);

my $hiqHEADER =
# Describing complex tns:hiqHEADER
#     {urn:openscape-voice}hiqHEADER
# xmlns:tns       urn:openscape-voice

# is a tns:hiqGLOBALHEADER
{ # sequence of InterfaceWSDL, OperatorId, ClientId

  # is a xs:string
  # is nillable, hence value or NIL
  # is optional
  InterfaceWSDL => "NIL",

  # is a xs:string
  # is nillable, hence value or NIL
  # is optional
  OperatorId => "myid",

  # is a xs:string
  # is nillable, hence value or NIL
  # is optional
  ClientId => "NIL", }
;

# Body part 'Body' is content for element tns:GetBGList3
my $Body =
# Describing complex tns:GetBGList3
#     {urn:openscape-voice}GetBGList3
# xmlns:tns       urn:openscape-voice
# xmlns:xs        http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

# is an unnamed complex
{ # sequence of GetBGListRequest

  # is a tns:GetBGListRequest
  GetBGListRequest =>
  { # sequence of OperatorId, NumberPlanName, BGName,
    #   DNReserveEnabled, Paging, GetBGListDataOptionList,
    #   GetBGListSortList

    # is a xs:string
    # is nillable, hence value or NIL
    # is optional
    OperatorId => "myid",

    # is a xs:string
    # is nillable, hence value or NIL
    # is optional
    NumberPlanName => "NIL",

    # is a xs:string
    # is nillable, hence value or NIL
    # is optional
    BGName => "NIL",

    # is a xs:boolean
    # is nillable, hence value or NIL
    # is optional
    DNReserveEnabled => "true",

    # is a tns:Paging
    # is nillable, as: Paging => NIL
    # is optional
    Paging =>
    { # sequence of PageSize, PageNumber

      # is a xs:int
      PageSize => 42,

      # is a xs:int
      PageNumber => 42, 
    },

    # is a tns:GetBGListDataOptionList
    # is nillable, as: GetBGListDataOptionList => NIL
    # is optional
    GetBGListDataOptionList =>
    { # sequence of GetBGListDataOptionItem

      # is a tns:GetBGListDataOptionItem
      # occurs any number of times
      GetBGListDataOptionItem =>
      [ { # sequence of GetBGListDataOption

          # is a xs:string
          # is nillable, hence value or NIL
          # is optional
          # Enum: BgListDataInclBGDisplayNum
          GetBGListDataOption => "BgListDataInclBGDisplayNum", 
         }, 
      ], 
    },

    # is a tns:GetBGListSortList
    # is nillable, as: GetBGListSortList => NIL
    # is optional
    GetBGListSortList =>
    { # sequence of GetBGListSortElement

      # is a tns:GetBGListSortElement
      # occurs any number of times
      GetBGListSortElement =>
      [ { # sequence of GetBGListSortType, SortOrder

          # is a xs:string
          # is nillable, hence value or NIL
          # is optional
          # Enum: BGListSortBGName
          GetBGListSortType => "BGListSortBGName",

          # is a xs:string
          # is nillable, hence value or NIL
          # is optional
          # Enum: SortOrderAscending SortOrderDescending
          SortOrder => "SortOrderAscending", 
        },
      ], 
    },
  }, 
}
;

# Call with the combination of parts.
my @params = (
    hiqHEADER => $hiqHEADER,
    Body => $Body,
);

my ($answer, $trace) = $wsdl->call($ope,@params);
```

Running the script creates the warning

```
warning: unused values GetBGListRequest
```

Not providing the $Body creates this error:

```
error: required value for element `GetBGListRequest' missing at tns:GetBGList3
```

This means: the Body seems to be requested / needed to build the request - but finally it isn't added to the request.

The question now is: How can I achieve it to get the body added to the request, too?

Comment: I am not familar with SOAP. Can you give more details about the server at 
 "http://127.0.0.1:80/test" ? What is needed to set it up so we can try reproduce? See [mcve] for more information

Comment: You can take this script as it is and run it (maybe adding a shebang). Before, you have to download the wsdl file by clicking on the given link in the original post. Unzip it and put it in the same directory where you put the script and start it.
The destination is set to port 80 localhost. Behind it, there is just a normal http server - you could change it to any other destination you like to.
If you trace the connection (with wireshark), you will see, that the client only sends the header, but not the body. That's the key point!

Comment: I am able to reproduce this error now (no body in the request). I am not familar with WSDL, can I ask you how you arrived at the form of `$Body` and `$hiqHEADER` that you input to `$wsdl->call()`. I was not able to figure this out by reading the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Compile::WSDL11)